# Magento - Moving Cart_sidebar to top.phtml

Tags: php, magento

I'm looking to move the cart_sidebar up into top.phtml, It's a rather simple move that i've done several times, however I am having 0 luck doing it now that I'm running Magento 1.5.1.

did they change something significant?

see code being used below.

checkout.xml

```
<reference name="mini_cart_top">
    <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="mini_cart_top"  template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

page.xml

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
    <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="mini_cart_top" as="mini_cart_top" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"/>
other misc code...
```

top.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mini_cart_top'); ?>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

catalog.xml

```
<reference name="top.menu">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.topnav" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml"/>
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="mini_cart_top" as="mini_cart_top" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"/>

        </reference>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've moved this successfully in 1.5

You've put the cart_sidebar XML block into the header block which would allow you to use it in header.phtml, not in top.phtml.

top.phtml is a similar block to sidebar.phtml - it should only really contain the categories navigation, not the shopping cart.

If you can clarify where you want to put it and why, I'll tell you how to get it working.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i've been using top.phtml for a small navigation ribbon containing breadcrumbs and a link to a modal dropdown shopping cart. due to the formatting of my header and column layout using topnav was the easiest solution for this ribbon

Comment: managed to get the cart to display in top.phtml.. would only pass through catalog.xml not page.xml for some reason, only problem is. its appearing at the bottom of the top.phtml code.  is there a way to specify the exact location it will appear in the code? as previously stated I would like for it to appear in the dropdown which requires specifically calling the cart in top.phtml.

Comment: added to original post the contents of the block, if you wanna see the full file just let me know. just noticed thats pulling the cart below top.phtml not into it.. must have more coffee... any ideas for pulling it into top.phtml?

Comment: It will order the blocks in the order they're defined in in the XML. All you need to do is use your original code in the top.phtml file to determine where it shows up: **<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mini_cart_top'); ?>**

Comment: unfortunately that is not displaying anything from mini_cart_top.

Comment: Strange, I did it in the same way and it worked perfectly. How about creating an entirely new phtml file for your top cart? SO you end up with:

**<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="mini_cart_top" template="checkout/cart/topcart.phtml"/>**

And try that instead.

Comment: got a kind of work around going, since i could add the code below top.phtml i just left the divs open from top, and threw the content in to a duplicate sidebar.phtml. not the prettiest way but it does seem to be holding up.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar, but putting a really cool sidebar cart that works with jquery in the top links and made by Damodar Bashyal from [Technooze](http://technooze.com/blog/92/118/Magento-add-sidebar-mini-cart-on-the-header).
Had to install jquery first (see how [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/javascript_related/how_to_use_jquery_1.2.6_lastest_with_prototype))

(I'm sure there is cleaner ways to do it, but me no expert)
So to get them into the top links (where *Checkout*, *My Account* and *My Cart* links are) I first made disappear the My Cart link to avoid duplicates and then I included the Checkout.xml code for the sidebar_cart into that block.
My Checkout.xml part:

```
<reference name="top.links">
        <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
            <!-- erase cart link:
            <action method="addCartLink"></action> -->
            <!-- I also erase Checkout link - no point for me: 
            <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>-->
            <!--and we include the sidebar_cart block into page/template/links-->
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Of course we have to uncomment the after in the following "header" reference.

Then in page.xml I include the block for it to appear in the top links:

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks">
        <!-- include sidebar cart -->
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" as="topcart" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"/>
        <!-- close block here -->
        </block>
        <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
```

Next thing I include the call for the cart_sidebar in template/page/template/links.phtml just after the .

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topcart'); ?>
```

The rest is styling.

Comment: have to check on the xml files, because I'm having a blank checkout/cart site and checkout onepage is also blank. Will update as soon as fixed ! this is surely due to my messy way of working on the xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Moving Mini-cart to header in magento is really simple you just need to change your xml and you are done with it. below are steps by which we can move mini cart.

```
Step1. Open checkout.xml from location given below

/design/frontend/default/[your theme]/layout/checkout.xml

find the code below in file.

<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"/>
```

Step2. now open page.xml can be found at location given below

```
\design\frontend\default\[your theme]\layout\page.xml

in this file find the code given below

<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">

paste the the cart_sidebar block as shown below.

<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
    <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
    <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
    <label>Navigation Bar</label>

    <!--new added block -->
<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"/>
    <!--end new block -->
    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
</block>
```

Clear your cache.